# Вывод по id

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите кто знает. Мне нужно вывести все значения id из таблицы в виде ссылок, при их нажатии на странице должны отобразиться данные из таблицы где id равен выбранной нами ссылке. Например 1 2 3 4 5  нажимаем на 3, и выводятся данные из таблицы где id = 3. Я только смог вывести сами id в виде ссылок, что дальше делать вобще ума не приложу.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $page = "<a href='test.php/".$id."'>".$id."</a></br>";
            echo $page;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ссылка вида test.php?id=1

На странице test.php примерно следующий код:

```
<?php
$id = intval($_GET['id']); //получаем переданный ИД и приводим к типу ИНТ (чтоб руки не чесались)

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = ' . $id; // наш SQL на выборку
$queryResult = mysql_query($sql); // результат нашего запроса
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryResult); //получаем строку (один ИД? значит и строка будет одна)
echo 'ID : ' . $row['id'] . '<br />'; //выводим наши данные
...
```

Здесь еще стоит предусмотреть реакцию на ошибки и проверку на наличие результата, т.к. пока пользователь рассматривал страницу (а он мог ее рассматривать и сутки), за это время требуемая строка в таблице могла быть удалена.

Если не хотите заниматься оформлением вывода сами, то можно пробежаться по $row и вывести столбцы в таблице. Либо воспользоваться, например, комментарием тов. 'nick at homefeedback dot com' на [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Сейчас попробую, на счет получения id через get, как их правильно передать, если ссылки на той же самой странице, они там и должны быть всегда, пока я не передам все это на другую страницу. Походу я тупой, не могу вобще понять. Ну все равно спасибо

Comment: все разобрался, спасибо большое